# How to change height of ImageView through nslayout?

Tags: ios

I have ImageView. In Storyboard height of ImageView = 45. I need to change height = 70 programmatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on the constraint to highlight it, make an `IBOutlet` of the constraint in your header file of your controller and change the constraint's `constant` value as you please.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do it in code ?

Comment: Consider you've made an `IBOutlet` of type `NSLayoutConstraint` named `ImageViewHeghtConstraint`, in your code where you want to change your size just add this: `self.ImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 70.0f;`